# Convert a PowerShell script to exe Including an Exe file into it

Tags: powershell

I have a few Powershell scripts that I use to copy files and run installations with the required install steps included in the sript, i know how to convert these scripts into exes. I would like to know, how to include the files I am installing with the script in the powershell converted exe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to answer my own question for whom ever come across the same issue or need!
I had the way of doing this all along, but I didn't pay attention to details: For what I required which is to convert a .PS1 script that installs postgresql unattended, to an .exe file including(Postgres enbedded in the exe).

The best tool for this is the "PS1 to EXE" https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/PS1-To-EXE-Generator-d39e8be2 software, 
1. Load your ps1 file, make sure everything is working before hand.
2. Embed the the files you need for the ps1 to work (embed option is on the right column next to the "Options")

Then you can click the convert option
PS: Be sure to have the correct file path.

Answer (score 0):

This utility on github has proven very useful to me:

https://github.com/rzander/PS2EXE

It comes with a pretty straightforward GUI and command-line version, but only works with one PowerShell file.

I have modified a personal version to take multiple files and combine them into one executable. Let me know if you’re interested and I can upload it.

Comment: PowerGUI used to be able to bundle non-ps1 files into the compiled executable. I believe the compiled executable extracted the non-ps1 files into a system temp directory and referenced them from there if needed. Unfortunately PS2-EXE doesn't do this but PowerGUI does still work (mostly) if you can find a copy of it.
Bennett, if your version will combine non-ps1 files then yes I'd be up for a copy of it

Comment: I am having a look and will get back to you, thanks for the quick reply

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not support non-ps1 files. I’m not sure what program would help you with that, sorry!

Comment: Yeah this doesn't work for me! If i can find a way  of telling my script to look for this installer file inside the exe, would be great! because I can just leave the script has it is and continue.